# ZeroMQ Hello World Client - Server. Reply from Server apparently does not arrive

Tags: python, c++, zeromq

I am testing the examples of the [ZeroMQ framework](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) asynchronous library messaging to work in distributed applications, enabling the interoperability between programming languages.

My interest is that from a client application in C++ I can send a message and this is received in server application in python.

In order to this objective, I am using the following samples:

The client application in C++ is named `hwclient.cpp` and [is based in this code:](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwclient)

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);

    std::cout << "Connecting to hello world server…" << std::endl;
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:5555");

    //  Do 10 requests, waiting each time for a response
    for (int request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++) {
        zmq::message_t request (5);
        memcpy (request.data (), "Boti", 5);
        std::cout << "Sending " << request_nbr << "…" << std::endl;
        socket.send (request);

        //  Get the reply.
        zmq::message_t reply;
        socket.recv (&reply);

        // Print the reply, memory address ...
        std::cout << 'Mostrando reply' << &reply << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Received from server " << request_nbr << std::endl; reply;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The python server is named `hwserver.py` and [is based in this code](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:hwserver):

```
import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

while True:
    #  Wait for next request from client
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received request: %s" % message)

    print('hi')

    #  Do some 'work'
    time.sleep(1)

    #  Send reply back to client
    socket.send(b"World")
    print('Response sent')
```

I build the C++ client with `g++ hwclient.cpp -o client.out -lzmq` and execute the binary to send a message from client of this way:

```
bgarcial@elpug : ~/CLionProjects/ZeroMQ
[0] % ./client.out
Connecting to hello world server…
Sending 0…
17018666170x7ffcbea254d0
Received from server 0
Sending 1…
17018666170x7ffcbea254d0
Received from server 1
Sending 2…
17018666170x7ffcbea254d0
Received from server 2

bgarcial@elpug : ~/CLionProjects/ZeroMQ
[0] %
```

In the server side, the `Boti` string has been arrived!

```
[127] % python HelloWorldServer/zeromq_server.py
Received request: b'Boti\x00'
hi
Response sent
Received request: b'Boti\x00'
hi
Response sent
Received request: b'Boti\x00'
hi
Response sent
```

But I think that the code section `socket.send(b"World")` in the server is not executed because in my client does not arrive the `World` string ...

Is it possible that I am not receiving the reply in my c++ client of a suited way?

When I test the python server with a python client server, the reply from server arrives at client in a successful way ...

Why I cannot see the reply from server in my c++ application client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A) Assumptions about a not delivered message are not correct. Why?

The core logic ( actually the core, multiparty distributed-logic ) of the **`REQ/REP`** Scalable Formal Communication Pattern archetype is hard-wired so that if the **`REP`**-entity receives a **`REQ`**-message ( and never else , except with some recent API v4.+ delicate tweaking, to be utmost precise ), the **`REP`**-entity can ( and in your code will ) **`.send()`** a message to **`REQ`**-side.

Symmetrically, after the **`REQ`**-entity has fired its first message to **`REP`**-side, it can never send another "next" message, unless it has prior to that, **`.recv()`**-ed the **`REP`**-side response.

This symmetrical distributed-logic means, that if your server-side code reports positive acknowledgement of sending more than just one message, it on its own grounds itself represents a positive proof, that also the opposite side has been delivered each and every response from the server. ( For cases, where some messages got lost, you [may kindly read my other posts on the **risks of `REQ/REP` mutual dead-locks**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D) ).

So this has been solved as indeed an incorrect assumption, Q.E.D.

---

### B) Assumptions about an ill-delivered message content are not correct. Why?

ZeroMQ either delivers a completely correct message, or nothing at all.

This means, that in case a message has been both sent and delivered ( for the core distributed-logic reasoning kindly ref. above ), the only possible alternative is, that the message payload is correct, as no other option exists in ZeroMQ framework internalities.

**Proof:**
change this:

```
 // Print the reply, memory address ...
    std::cout << 'Mostrando reply' << &reply << std::endl;
```

into this:

```
 // Print the reply
    std::cout << 'Mostrando reply was delivered' << std::endl;
```

and you will straight see, where the problem is -- it is not in the ZeroMQ tools, but the way, how your code tried to present the **`&reply`** into a **`std::out`** output.

---

### C) Why I cannot see the reply from server?

Because you do not try to show it.

That simple.

In case you are still in doubts, may try to send it again back to the server and print it / match it there to see, both that it was delivered at all ( ref. A) above ) and that it was delivered correctly ( ref. B) above )

Q.E.D.

Comment: I understand that you tell me about of `REQ-REP` pattern. With the change that you refer me, I can see a number in the response in the `c++` client, this is a memory address of message arrived from python server?

Comment: I am printing the client message in the server, but I don't understand when you tell me that see both messages and *match it!*, I say this, because in my  client, I get the number like response from server. Is possible that I still cannot understand the logic core or I am confuse about of your recommendation. Can you orient me about it please? My apologies for my late response comments here .

Comment: No problem, you are welcome. So, the ZeroMQ-transport delivers each payload error-free ( or not at all ). There is also an API-call to "copy"-a-message-payload ( without trying to "open" the container, the less to interpret it ) and move the same "pre-packed" payload inside another message -- above advised to be sent back to the original sender. This "do-not-touch-and-send-back" enables you to receive the very the same payload back to the sending machine / language, where it should be easy to proof 1:1 "copy" was delivered back. There is nothing more complex in this "software-driven" loop-back

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer and comments from [@user3666197](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3666197/user3666197) I didnt`t have any inconvinient on the zeroMQ side.

Instead of it, I should addressed the problem  using C++.

I wanted to show the return message from the ptyhon server to the c++ client.

So, to my c++ client arrive the payload of the message, but I should make some cast or conversion of the response and then show the message as a string.

Then my c++ client will receive the python server response of this way:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "math.h"

int main ()
{
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    clock_t t_ini, t_end;
    double secs;

    // We take the clock value before the call to process.
    t_ini = clock();

    std::cout << "Conectando al servidor python zeroMQ…" << std::endl;
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:5555");

    zmq::message_t request (20);
    memcpy (request.data (), "Hola Servidor Python", 20);
    socket.send (request);



    zmq::message_t reply;
    socket.recv (&reply);


    // I make cast conversion to string the response
    std::string replyMessage = std::string(static_cast<char *>(reply.data()), reply.size());

    std::cout << "Recibiendo respuesta desde el servidor: " + replyMessage << " "  << std::endl;

    t_end = clock();

    secs = (double)(t_end - t_ini) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;



    printf("%.16g miliseconds", secs * 1000.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Of this way I can view the response from server in text plain